# CentOS 7 and Dropbear

Tags: centos7, headless, dropbear

I have search this issue on serverfault.com but can't find anything.

On my Server I habe installed an crypted LVM CentOS 7 with Dropbear. On boot I can decrypt the hdd via direct keyboard input. But I want do this via SSH.

Is this possible via SSH decrypt an headless server.

thanks

Comment: You will have to do it over the console. If your server is on bare metal, you will need a remote management card.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. That i need an remote managment card i didnt know. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a remote management card. You must put dropbear and crypt-ssh into the initrd with dracut.

[dracut-crypt-ssh](https://github.com/dracut-crypt-ssh/dracut-crypt-ssh)